# Capture Image pasted in Rich Text Edit as public image to share over email

Tags: email, richtextarea

We have developed a custom email composer screen using rich text input component.

Problem we are facing is when the user copy an image or use image upload option the image is not visible when the client opens the email.

- It shows as image not available error.
- I know this is as per design. But I would like hear if there are alternate option to capture the image details after it is pushed to the editor and then create is as a Document and then create a public link and copy the image and automatically replace that in the editor.
- Please let me know if my ask was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these embedded images require authentication to see them. An email user wouldn't be authenticated.  See [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdbhfUAB/support-the-images-in-rtf-field-in-email-message)

You can fetch those images using the REST API and then stuff them into something (like a `Document` or public `ContentAsset` or `StaticResource`).

The REST API ([documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_rich_text_image_retrieve.htm))

```
/services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/sObject/id/richTextImageFields/fieldName/contentReferenceId
```

where

- `sObject` is the Object where the RTF is saved (like `Lead`)
- `id` is the id of the record
- `contentReferenceId` is taken from the  tag, attribute `refId`. You'll have to parse your RTF field to find this

From the doc

```
   <img alt=\"Sarah Loehr.\" 
   src=\"https://MyDomainName.file.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?
   eid=00QRM000003ZfDb&amp;
   feoid=00NRM000001E73j&amp;
   refid=0EMRM00000002Ip\"></img>
}
```

Once you've retrieved the binary, you'll need to store it elsewhere that can be used in a publicly available location.